Azure Pipelines - Run a stage multiple times
I am working with azure pipelines and I have some stages with jobs inside it.
I am trying to figure it out how can I run a stage 3 times before moving to next stage.
stages:
- stage: SomeTests
  jobs:
  - job:
    ...

- stage: Installation 
  dependsOn: SomeTests
  jobs:
  - job:
    ...

I'd like to run stage SomeTests 3 times and then run stage Installation.
How can I do that?

Just out of curiosity, why do you need to do that? Could you please provide more context? There might be a better solution to your problem as compared to running a stage N times.

It's for testing purposes. Can you help? Maybe with a loop? But I don't know how to do it. Even though I researched I am not finding a way to do it

You can use a loop to generate multiple stages (or jobs) that run exactly the same code, but it won't be the same stage. Do you want to reuse the stage but using different configuration ( e.g. different environments)?

Can you post an example with the code I provided please?

I don't need to reuse anything. Just run 3 times. This is for testing purposes only. If you could be so kind to provide the code for the loop it would be awesome

Did my answer help?

You can declare a parameter of type object containing an array (where each element contains information about the stage to run) and then loop through the parameter and generate a stage for each element.
Generating stages that run sequentially
By default stages run sequentially, but if you need to define custom dependencies you can do the following:
parameters:
  - name: testStages
    type: object
    default:
      - name: someTests1
        displayName: 'Some Tests 1'
        dependsOn: [] # run in parallel (first stage)
      - name: someTests2
        displayName: 'Some Tests 2'
        dependsOn:
          - someTests1
      - name: someTests3
        displayName: 'Some Tests 3'
        dependsOn:
          - someTests1
          - someTests2

stages:
  - ${{ each stage in parameters.testStages }}:
    - stage: ${{ stage.name }}
      displayName: ${{ stage.displayName }}
      dependsOn: ${{ stage.dependsOn }}
      jobs:
        - job: job_${{ stage.name }}
          steps:
            - checkout: none
            - script: echo ${{ stage.name }}
  
  - stage: Installation
    displayName: Installation
    dependsOn: ${{ parameters.testStages.*.name }}
    jobs:
      - job: job_Installation
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - script: echo Installation

Queuing a new pipeline - stages:

Stages sequence:

Generating stages that run in parallel
As an alternative, you can run the test stages in parallel by setting dependsOn: []:
parameters:
  - name: testStages
    type: object
    default:
      - name: someTests1
        displayName: 'Some Tests 1'
      - name: someTests2
        displayName: 'Some Tests 2'
      - name: someTests3
        displayName: 'Some Tests 3'

stages:
  - ${{ each stage in parameters.testStages }}:
    - stage: ${{ stage.name }}
      displayName: ${{ stage.displayName }}
      dependsOn: [] # <----------------------- run stages in parallel (no dependencies)
      jobs:
        - job: job_${{ stage.name }}
          steps:
            - checkout: none
            - script: echo ${{ stage.name }}
  
  - stage: Installation
    displayName: Installation
    dependsOn: ${{ parameters.testStages.*.name }}
    jobs:
      - job: job_Installation
        steps:
          - checkout: none
          - script: echo Installation

Queuing a new pipeline - stages:

Stages sequence:

Recommended reading

Runtime parameters
Parameter data types
Filtered arrays


I have a question isn't another way to do this? I mean If I want to run the test 100 times do i have to create 100 parametrs?

@H.N. there is no equivalent of a for i=0; i++; i<100 loop in Azure Pipelines but there are always some workarounds for people with creativity/imagination :-)
For example, you can use nested loops to generate based on 2 or more parameters to generate all the stages you need. Or, as an alternative, for each iteration use a stages template with multiple stages inside.

ok thanks for your help  :)
